# Sorting using C#'s Linq library

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am creating a C# 2010 application using .NET Framework 3.5.

I have a datagridview that contains a few columns and rows [obviously]. I save this datagridview's rows in a structure of the form `List<string[]>`. I also have a `List<double>` which contains coefficients. I want to sort the structure by the coefficients using the  `System.LINQ` library. I have attempted the following:

> ```
> var linq_Query_rowrates =
>     from rw in rows
>     orderby matchrate descending
>     select rw;
> ```

This underlines the rows in the query and shows the following error:

> Error 1   Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type '`System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>`'.  '`OrderByDescending`' not found.  Are you missing a reference to '`System.Core.dll`' or a using directive for '`System.Linq`'?

**Is it possible to sort this kind of structure using the LINQ library and if yes, how?**

Note: I am aware of a lot of other methods to accomplish this, I am just interested in doing it using the LINQ library.

Note: matchrate is not a member of rows but using a member of rows does not work either.

LATER EDIT: Maybe it should be something like this?

```
        var linq_Query_rowrates =
            from rw in rows
            join rate in matchrate
            on matchrate equals rows
            orderby matchrate descending
            select rw;
```

Comment: Have you referenced 'System.Core.dll' and included a `using System.Linq;` directive in your source file?

Comment: @dtb, yes, I have included using System.Linq; and have referenced the dll.

Comment: How are rows and coefficients related? By index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ugly, but it's Linq:

```
            List<string[]> rows = null;
            List<double> coefficients = null;

            rows
                .Select((row, index) => new { Row = row, Index = index })
                .Join(coefficients
                            .Select(
                                (coefficient, index) => new { Coefficient = coefficient, Index = index }), 
                                x => x.Index, 
                                x => x.Index, 
                                (rowIndex, coefIndex) => new { Row = rowIndex.Row, Coefficient = coefIndex.Coefficient })
                .OrderBy(x => x.Coefficient)
                .Select(x => x.Row);
```

I haven't tested it though. It should be possible to transform it to query form.

Comment: I need it to sort descending actually. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Replace `OrderBy` with `OrderByDescending`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `matchrate` is a member of `rw`, you need to use the following syntax:

```
var linq_Query_rowrates =
    from rw in rows
    orderby rw.matchrate descending
    select rw;
```

**Update**

Ideally, you would have a navigation property for your rate relationship, so your query would look like this:

```
var linq_Query_rowrates =
    from rw in rows
    orderby rw.rate.matchrate descending
    select rw;
```

Another option is to perform a join. But joins in LINQ are ugly, and I try to avoid them.

Comment: It is not a member but using a member of rows doesn't work either.

Comment: You can't order by something that isn't a member of rw's type.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to sort rows by matchrate using only LINQ?

Comment: Perhaps something like this might work?             var linq_Query_rowrates =
                from rw in rows
                join rate in matchrate
                on matchrate equals rows
                orderby matchrate descending
                select rw;

Comment: Yes, you can do this with a join.

Comment: See, that's the problem, the error I have mentioned in the beginning still appears, no matter what I try.

Comment: Can you add `rate` as a navigation property to your `rw` type? See my update.

Answer (score 2):

If your collection of coefficients are meant to link with your collection of string[], why do you build 2 seperate, unrelated lists? Surely it would be more robust to just build a very simple structure to hold all the information to ensure there are always appropriate coefficients for each row. It also makes sorting very straightforward.

```
public struct CoefficientRow
{
    public double Coefficient;
    public string[] Cells;

    public CoefficientRow(double c, string[] cells)
    {
        this.Coefficient = c;
        this.Cells = cells;
    }
}
```

Sorting becomes a breeze...

```
List<CoefficientRow> rows = new List<CoefficientRow>();
//populate the list...
var orderedRows = rows.OrderBy(cr => cr.Coefficient);
//or
var orderedRows = rows.OrderByDescending(cr => cr.Coefficient);
```

Inserting them to the datagridview is also still quite easy:

```
foreach(var row in rows)
    this.dgvDataView.Rows.Add(row.Cells);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you could use .Net4, user676571's answer simplifies to:

```
IEnumerable<string> query = rows
  .Zip(coefficients, (r, c) => new {row = r, coef = c})
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.coef)
  .Select(x => x.row);
```